# script not responding to open weather api

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to use geolocations to get current coordinates and then input that into the open weather api to get data back and display it through html.

This is my script:

```
var lat =0;
var long =0;
function getLocation(){
  var x = document.getElementByID('demo');
  if (navigator.gelocation){
    navigator.gelocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
      lat = position.coords.latitude;
      long = position.coord.longitude;
        $('#coord').html('Here:'+lat+ 'here'+long);
    });
  } else {
    x.innerHTML= 'Geolocation not supported';
  }
};

function getWeather(callback){
  $.ajax({
    dataType:"jsonp",
    url:'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='+lat+'&lon='+long+'&APPID=f2d2480cdd1ef46b9f10dd6860cb1a3e',
    succes: callback
  });
}
getWeather(function(data){
  var temp = data.main.temp;
  var description = data.weather[0].description;
  $("#temp").html(data.main.temp);
  $('#desc').html(data.weather[0].description);
});

$('document').ready(function(){
  getLocation();
  getWeather();
});
```

and this is the html:

```
<div id = "city">
  <h4>city</h4>
</div>
<div id="temp">
  <h4>temp</h4>
</div>
<div id= "desc">
  <h4>description</h4>
</div>
<div id= "coord">
  <h4>coord</h4>
</div>
```

I am currently doing this project on codepen.io here's the [link](http://codepen.io/kimps/pen/xRxpod) I am really unsure of what I am doing wrong. I've looked at other example codes out there too and I can't spot the mistake I am making. Could I please get some help as to why the code seem to not respond.

Comment: It seems you don't have any element with "Demo" id. Check it out. And I think you should remove single quotes in $('document'). Also correct  this: getElementByID -> getElementById

Comment: I solved some of your problems but are you trying to call coords as well? I am not seeing them anywhere in the jQuery code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of spelling issues (succes instead of success, getElementByID instead of getElementById, using demo element which is not existent). On top of that there is issue with code organization:

1. getWeather() function is called with no parameters in second instance
2. getWeather() should execute after getLocation() updates coordinates, which is asynchronous. You can use Promises to organize code, or await from ES7
3. In some browsers (Chrome) you should be over HTTPS to get geolocation, but openweathermap public API available only over HTTP, therefore this codepen won't work in Chrome
4. Separation of concerns: every function should do one job, e.g. either get data or render it

Final [codepen](http://codepen.io/maximvorobjov/pen/YpPPXG)

```
function getLocation() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (navigator.geolocation)
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => resolve(position.coords), 
        err => reject(err.message))
    else
      reject('Geolocation not supported')
  })
}

function getWeather(coord) {
  return $.when($.ajax('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='+coord.latitude+'&lon='+coord.longitude+'&APPID=f2d2480cdd1ef46b9f10dd6860cb1a3e'));
}

function drawCoord(coord) {
  $("#coord").html(`Here: ${coord.latitude};${coord.longitude}`)
  return coord
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  getLocation()
    .then(drawCoord)
    .then(getWeather)
    .then(function(data){
        var temp = data.main.temp;
        var description = data.weather[0].description;
        $("#temp").html(data.main.temp);
        $('#desc').html(data.weather[0].description);
        })
    .catch(e => $(".error").html(e))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several minor issues with the code. Things that you could've figure out yourself if you looked a bit closely.

1. Thing that I found is that you were having a typo when returning the callback on `getWeather` function:

   ```
   function getWeather(callback){
     $.ajax({
       dataType:"jsonp",
       url:'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='+lat+'&lon='+long+'&APPID=f2d2480cdd1ef46b9f10dd6860cb1a3e',
       succes: callback
     });
   }
   ```

Your mistake is here: `succes: callback`, it should be `success`.

1. Is that you put single quotes on `$('document').ready(function()`. Remove the single quotes around `document`.
2. You had another typo here: `var x = document.getElementByID('demo');`, it should be `var x = document.getElementById('demo');`

3.Another problem you had was that you misplaced one of your id's again. You where trying to call `demo` but there was not one specified:

```
 var x = document.getElementById('demo');
```

Instead you should put down the `coord` id that you are using for geolocation like this:  `var x = document.getElementById('coord');`

Comment: thanks! Should've checked for little errors more, didn't realize the amount of typos I had.

Comment: @kimpster if my answer was helpful, ca you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

This is what should work, at least it works for me:
1- Change "long" variable name to "longt" (I think you cannot use "long" because it's a variable type.
2- Check the spell of "geolocation" (you have misspelled "gelocation")

```
var lat =0;
var longt =0;
function getLocation(){
  var x = document.getElementById('coord');
  if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
      lat = position.coords.latitude;
      longt = position.coords.longitude;
        $('#coord').html('Here:'+lat+ 'here'+longt);
    });
  } else {
    x.innerHTML= 'Geolocation not supported';
  }
};

function getWeather(callback){
  $.ajax({
    dataType:"jsonp",
    url:'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='+lat+'&lon='+longt+'&APPID=f2d2480cdd1ef46b9f10dd6860cb1a3e',
    succes: callback
  });
}
getWeather(function(data){
  var temp = data.main.temp;
  var description = data.weather[0].description;
  $("#temp").html(data.main.temp);
  $('#desc').html(data.weather[0].description);
});

$('document').ready(function(){
  getLocation();
  getWeather();
});
```